# Sync between HomeKit button and UI Switch?

Tags: node-red

currently I try to create a flow, where I can turn a device on with my iPhone or with the ui switch.
This works fine but now I try that the another button will become the signal too and can try it with the another button of.
If I try it my relay will have a loop.

Will it work or does have someone a idea?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here. Can you try and add some more detail (may be a diagram). Also the button ui node has a option to prevent message pass through which should be used to change state without sending a command.

Comment: Will add tomorrow more details and a screenshot of my node red